# SQL: Cleansing dates from OCR'ed documents

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, ocr, data-cleaning

I have a variety of dates from several `.pdf` documents that were OCR'ed, the dates have imported in the format `DD/MM/YYYY`. As the documents are photocopies they are not optimal quality resulting in issues where the dates struggled to distinguish between `/` and `1` as follows:

**Issue:** `0110212015`
`01/0212015`
`01102/2015`

**Desired Output:** `01/02/2015`

As the strings have retained their length of the original dates I was hoping to simply replace the character in `Nth` position with `/`. To my knowledge and that gained from searching, SQL does not have a function that simple. Are their substitute or replace functions that can target the exact `1`'s I need to change? Or can I reconstruct the string using my existing values?

Comment: In SQL Server, [`SUBSTRING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187748.aspx) will allow you to extract the portions of the strings. Then reconstitute them with [concatenation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms177561.aspx) and convert to a real date.

Comment: @MattGibson worked perfectly `SUBSTRING(LTRIM([Date]),1,2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(LTRIM([Date]),4,2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(LTRIM([Date]),7,4) AS [Cleansed_Date]`. Post as answer and I will mark your response as correct if you like.

Comment: Personally, I'd probably accept one of the `STUFF` answers; there's many different ways of doing this, and given that they're all pretty much non-standard across different database systems, none of them is going to be a "perfect" solution. (`STUFF` is probably neater on SQL Server, but SUBSTRING and concatenate may be more readily readable to people coming from other languages...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server does have a function to do that... it's called [STUFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

So your expression would look something like:

```
STUFF(STUFF (DateString , 3, 1, '/'), 6, 1, '/')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use STUFF function:

```
select stuff(stuff('0110212015',3,1,'/'),6,1,'/')
```